# He is also..., writes... - sentence structure, grammar

Tags: grammar

> Ed is also Technology Editor for Certification Magazine, **writes** for numerous TechTarget Web sites, and writes a twice-monthly newsletter, “Must Know News,” for CramSession.com. In his spare time, Ed likes to shoot pool, cook, and spend time with his wife Dina and his son Gregory. He also likes to explore the world away from the keyboard with his trusty Labrador retriever, Blackie.

To me it feels like there needs to be the preposition **and** placed before **writes** for grammatical consistency. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence you are referring to is a list. Normally, *and* is only used a separator just before the last item in the list. So I find no fault with the way it is being used here.

However, if I was going to nit-pick, I would suggest substituting one of the occurrences of *write* with something else (e.g. *authors* or *is the author of*) in order to avoid a rather clumsy repetition.

Comment: You must have the same nits over there that we do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rephrase the first sentence as follow avoiding the repetition of *writes* and the use of *and* before it.

Ed is also technology Editor for Certification Magazine. He writes for numerous TechTarget Web sites  and a twice-monthly newspaper....